# Picasso fails to load an image but provides no error message?

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I'm running into an issue where on some devices (non-nexus devices) on varying versions of Android (KitKat and Marshmellow) are always throwing an error when I try to use picasso to load an image into an image view. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, it provides no error message other than calling the "onError" method.

Things I've checked:

- The image string is non-null and points to a valid string on the device.
- picasso is non-null.
- Switching on logging to see if anything relevant shows up there (it doesn't).

The code:

```
picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);
picasso.load(mSourceImageUrl)
    .resize(mWidthPx, mHeightPx)
    .centerCrop()
    .error(R.drawable.shape_rounded_rectangle_gray)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.shape_rounded_rectangle_gray)
    .into(imageView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& onSuccess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
             System.out.println("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& onError");
        }
});
```

Comment: It looks strange. Have you tried to pass a Uri instead the String path? And also try to add the "file:"-prefix to your String.

Comment: I had already tried passing the Uri, and the String had the "file:" prefix when I printed it. *However* I solved this issue, see answer below.

Comment: Ok, seems confusing, but nevertheless I consider this like a workaround, but it would be interesting to solve the original issue. However if it is reliable for you  - then that's fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved by switching from Picasso to Glide. Worked on all of my test devices. I know my original question was relatively generic, but if you're encountering the same thing (picasso won't load your image and won't print an error) see if using a different library will help. Glide is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

What was image size? Generally Picasso dont load image of size >=1MB and show no error